# How can I make a subselection in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Like this my query is working fine:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM projects WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
    $pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         echo "ok";
}
```

But when I add a subselection then I get a blank page:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *
    (SELECT * FROM animals WHERE projects.animal=animals.id) AS animal
    FROM projects WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
    $pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         echo "ok";
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131325/pdo-preparing-with-subqueries

Comment: Nothing to do with PDO. Try the query in a MySQL client.

Comment: The syntax is off. It should be "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS animal JOIN Projects " etc etc. The "temporary table" (between double quotes because that's not exactly a temp table) must still be considered as a table in the query. You have to define its join too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN to have both tables.

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *
FROM projects
INNER JOIN animals ON projects.animal=animals.id
WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
$pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo "ok";
}
```

Try this query beacuse this query will return all the projects that have an animal associated in table animals.

I think is this that you want

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM projects 
    LEFT JOIN animals ON projects.animal=animals.id
    WHERE project_id = :project_id ');  
    $pdo->execute(array('project_id' => $project_id));
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         echo "ok";
}
```