# MySQL INSERT with a field coming from another table fails

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I Need to insert data in a table but 1 of the fields will come from another table but not working...
Code as below:

```
   //Save payment to table paylog
   $sql  = "INSERT INTO `paylog`(`payment_id`, `date_approved`, `newcredit`, `before`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$payment->id,$dateApproved,
          $payment->transaction_amount,(SELECT credit from tokens WHERE token=$payment->external_reference LIMIT 1));
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
```

Assistance welcome
Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move that SELECT subquery up inside of `$sql`, keep `$payment->external_reference` as a binded parameter.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132551/7977859